# Blue parts on the trees

Tags: chromatic-aberration, color-blue, masks

How can I reduce or mask in[image: nature] LRoom blue parts on the trees (on the line between the sky and the trees) ?

Comment: Try Lens correction -> chromatic aberration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do these "redshifts" and "blueshifts" come from?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19372/where-do-these-redshifts-and-blueshifts-come-from)

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56546/how-to-fix-chromatic-aberration-with-free-software

Comment: And http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35913/how-can-chromatic-aberration-be-corrected-within-photoshop

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13460/how-do-i-use-the-chromatic-aberration-correction-tools-in-lightroom

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Lightroom's controls for fringing. From the looks of it, it looks like it should be on the "purple side" of blue, so heading into "Defringe" in "Lens Correction" and setting Purple Hue's selection to 0 on the lower end and being careful with the range you choose and the amount of defringing should mean you get rid of it but still keep the saturation of the sky.

Else, using the upper end of Green would be the next step.

Comment: The latest version of Lightroom now has a color picker tool for defringing which makes this process even easier. Click the picker, click the fringing, done.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try! I've messed something with pick up tool, so maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These blue or purple tints are called chromatic aberration. They are caused when some lenses slightly split the wavelengths of light . Usually they are less in more expensive lenses.  You can use colour fringing or lens correction tools to reduce these

Comment: Thank you! I' succeed somehow, but when the photo is no good it's not helping. So I'll use it only for small "problems" and try shooting better. Please tell me is any filter reduce this cases???

Comment: @gipsy you can use the HUE/SATURATION Tools from the edit menu and click on the ble fringes and turn down the saturation. This will make them lose colour and become black or grey ( which will not affect the pic in or make it worse)